# Clone the CRIU project from github, and make

Tags: software-installation

git clone  https://github.com/xemul/criu.git criu
cd criu
make clean
make
make install

I used the above command to clone and make. Clone is succesfull, but for make shows error 
1. fatal error: netlink/netlink.h: no such file or directory.
2. compilation terminated 
   /build.mk:119:criu/linetlink.o
   criu/makefile:76: criu/biult-in.o

and "make install" shows error as
cannot remove '/usr/local/share/man/man8/criu.8':permission denied

Comment: 1) What is the question?  2) Don't add terminal text as screenshot, copy&paste and format text into question instead.

Comment: I had fun building this software. The documentation for it is very bad, and it's in several different places depending on what you want to do with the software. Answering this question would not be fun because whatever you do with the software won't work until you've become familiar with the documentation. Please read the documentation and try to install it including all its dependencies. If it says `--no-recommends` then add this flag so you don't install too much, then comment if you get stuck.